# NSPersistentContainer Lightweight Migrations in Core Data iOS10 +

Tags: swift, core-data, ios10, nspersistentcontainer

I have added a new data model. Added a few new attributes to an Entity. Told xCode to use the new version. Am I right in thinking that if using **NSPersistentContainer**, that's all I have to do and xCode will automatically perform the lightweight migration for me?

Im confused as many posts around lightweight migration say I have to now create an **NSPersistentStoreDescription** set a few properties to True and pass this to the **NSPersistentContainer**

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "<#my store#>")
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url:(container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url)!)

description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true

container.persistentStoreDescriptions =  [description]
```

However I think this is now redundant. I know that 
**.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically** & **.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically** are both **True** by default so I know I no longer need to set those to true but is any of the code required since iOS 10?

Comment: If you are sure about the migration to the newer model can be inferred by the CoreData automatically then those variables are redundant.